# Fresh CentOS 6.2 / Ubuntu Server Installation on VMWare ESXi - can connect to LAN net but not Internet

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, vmware-esxi

I have configured a fresh CentOS 6.2 installation on VMWare ESXi with an E1000 NIC, static IP, defined a correct default gateway, subnet mask, and DNS servers.

I use a pfSense as my virtual router/firewall and I can `ping` other hosts in the LAN net as well as hosts over the L2L VPN without issue.

However, when I try to `ping 8.8.8.8` it fails. When performing a `traceroute`, the only hop it gets to is the first to `10.2.1.1` (the default gateway).

I have many Windows hosts behind the same firewall/router and they can connect to the Internet without issue. (If you cannot tell, I'm not a linux guy.)

I have confirmed that NetworkManager is not running.

I am scratching my head here - is it a VMWare issue? An MTU issue? CentOS issue?

EDIT 1: Now onto pfSense. Check in Edit log to see old content.

My routes table looks ok (blanked out my WAN default gateway, but it is right):

```
default xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx UGS 0   71607842    1500    em0
8.8.4.4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx UGHS    0   86984   1500    em0  
8.8.8.8 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx UGHS    0   101336  1500    em0
```

And States filtered for `8.8.8.8`

```
icmp    8.8.8.8:1551 <- 10.2.1.99   0:0 
icmp    10.2.1.99:1551 -> 10.2.1.1:38695 -> 8.8.8.8 0:0 
icmp    8.8.8.8:1714 <- 10.2.1.99   0:0 
icmp    10.2.1.99:1714 -> 10.2.1.1:61003 -> 8.8.8.8 0:0
```

All `0:0`?

Comment: Can you confirm that your pfSense box is not blocking the traffic?

Comment: Yes, it is not blocking traffic. Firewall logs are clear. I have other hosts set up in a similar fashion with no issue

Comment: Does it just time out when failing, or do you get an unreachable response from somewhere?  I'd be inclined to point to an issue with the pfSense config first - is the traffic being sent over the VPN tunnel unintentionally?

Comment: Could you paste the content of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` and `/etc/resolv.conf` here please? Also, please paste the output of the `netstat -rn` command.

Comment: @jshin47 this sounds vaguely like a routing issue having to do with VMWare, where the linux instance knows the default route, but the router doesn't know about the linux host.  Can the default gateway ping the linux instance?

Comment: @cjc yes, 10.2.1.1 can ping the linux instance. By the way, if it matters, I am using a dual pfSense setup with CARP, so 10.2.1.1 = 10.2.1.100, 101 but 100 is master, 101 is slave

Comment: Can you do some sort of tcpdump or network sniffing on the router?

Comment: @cjc, and just in case, I changed default gateway just now to .100 (the master) and restarted networking using `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`... no dice. I changed it back

Comment: @cjc, just updated question with output of `tcpdump -i eth0` while running a ping 8.8.8.8

Comment: Do you use VMware NIC teaming for the ESX vSwitch? If so what policy is set?

Comment: I'm curious what's happening at layer two. Please rerun that background ping with tcpdump -e option. Also please post the results of `arp` .

Comment: @Ryan I added two lines of output from that command, but almost all of the output was related to my shell session.

Comment: Do a "tcpdump -e host 8.8.8.8" to filter on the traffic we're testing.  Would it be possible to do something similar on the gateway, actually?  I'm not convinced this is something you can diagnose from inside the Linux instance.

Comment: @cjc, done... it's been added to my question now.

Comment: So, what we see is the packet leaving eth0 on the Linux box, with the destination as the ethernet device with MAC 00:00:5e:00:01:0b.  I assume this is the gateway (can you verify that?).  Nothing comes back.  You'll need to run a similar tcpdump or network sniff on the gateway, as said earlier.  All we can tell from the tcpdump run on the Linux instance is that packets leave.  We can't tell why the response isn't coming back.

Comment: @cjc FYI that MAC is just a placeholder for VRRP.

Comment: @cjc I have posted the output of a `tcpdump -i em1 host 10.2.1.99` from the `pf` device

Comment: @Ryan thanks , I couldnt find that in the pfSense ARP table and I was wondering why

Comment: I got nothing.  Packets are clearly coming out of the Linux instance, but either aren't making it past the firewall or the response packet is not coming back correctly.  I think you'll need to look at pfsense  configuration at this point.

Comment: But I am able to `ping 8.8.8.8` without issue from all of my Windows hosts behind the firewall. Also, I am able to ping it from `pf` device itself.

Comment: Looks like the issue is localized to the pfsense. We can see from those two captures that packets are making it to the default gateway correctly. So now we run through a few things on the pfsense. Route tables would be a good place to start.

Comment: @Ryan, I went ahead and removed all that info to increase space. Now I've posted my routes table for pfSense, nothing unusual

Comment: Local interface entries? I'm curious if we have a router that's trying to route back to the wrong interface. Tcpdump on the wan side will also show if those pings are making it through the firewall. It's possible those pings are going out then just not making it back

Comment: @Ryan, I also posted the States filtered for expression 8.8.8.8 in web configurator. The result is four states with a `0:0` status.

Comment: @Ryan, again though why would this work for every windows host without issue but fail for a linux host?

Comment: If you wish to specifically examine the differences. Capturing the same info from a working windows box would be a good baseline. So a capture of a successful background ping with layer2 info.

Comment: @Ryan, thanks for your help... Max is right, it was a NAT problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem with NAT. In pfSense state table, the entries with three pieces should show: 1. Source IP, 2. NAT'ed IP, 3. Destination IP. In your case, the second piece is 10.2.1.1:X, which is the internal IP. You want to see the IP assigned to your pfSense by the ISP.

To confirm, try pinging from a working Windows system and compare the state table.

Comment: Thank you Max. The bounty is yours. In my CARP setup, I had a LAN address set for my advanced outbound NAT LAN-to-WAN rule rather than Interface address or another CARP address. Changing it fixed everything.

Comment: Huzzah! So, the Linux instance's traffic was being sent to 8.8.8.8 without being NAT'ed?

Comment: Yes, well in Advanced Outbound NAT, the address was set to `10.2.1.1`, which was asinine of me. I changed this value to `Interface Address` as well as CARP shared address, and both worked. Basically, it wanted a WAN address to use there and I was giving it a local address

Comment: @cjc It was NAT'ed but still using an internal IP rather than external. So 8.8.8.8 received a ping it couldn't route back to. Good catch Max